# Issue with performing an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery

Tags: sql

```
select 
    A.ACCT as acct, COUNT(TRANS_key) as payments
from 
    DEBT A 
join 
    TRANS B on B.DEBT_KEY = A.DEBT_KEY
join 
    TRANS_CODE C on C.TRANS_CODE = B.TRANS_CODE
join 
    CLIENT D on D.CLIENT_KEY = A.CLIENT_KEY
join 
    STATUS S on S.STAT_KEY = A. STAT_KEY
where 
    S.CATEGORY = 'A' and D.CLIENT_KEY = 43
```

Error:

> *Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an
>   aggregate or a subquery.*

I am getting the error above when running this. I am not sure if I should be joining these tables differently or not, but I need this to be working.

Comment: What table is `TRANS_KEY` defined on? My guess is you probably don't even need all those JOINs.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All other selects have to be group by. Use this

```
    select A.ACCT as acct, COUNT(TRANS_key) as payments

from DEBT A join TRANS B on B.DEBT_KEY = A.DEBT_KEY

join TRANS_CODE C on C.TRANS_CODE = B.TRANS_CODE

join CLIENT D on D.CLIENT_KEY = A.CLIENT_KEY

join STATUS S on S.STAT_KEY = A. STAT_KEY

where S.CATEGORY = 'A' and D.CLIENT_KEY = 43
GROUP BY A.ACCT
```

Comment: Wow I believe I did that and it didnt work the first 300 times, thank you haha.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
select A.ACCT as acct, COUNT(TRANS_key) as payments
from DEBT A 
join TRANS B on B.DEBT_KEY = A.DEBT_KEY
join TRANS_CODE C on C.TRANS_CODE = B.TRANS_CODE
join CLIENT D on D.CLIENT_KEY = A.CLIENT_KEY
join STATUS S on S.STAT_KEY = A. STAT_KEY
where S.CATEGORY = 'A' and D.CLIENT_KEY = 43
group by A.ACCT
```

You can't use a aggregate function like `count` that return just 1 result and a select that returns multiple. If you want to the count for every `a.acct` then do the above.